# Why am i getting an error when importing my data to the SQL database on python?

Tags: python, sql

So i tried to create a database from a youtube tutorial, but where executing the code, i get this error:
`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

I looked for comments under the YT video but no one seems to have the same issue.
Here is the code:

````
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

wiki = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'

tikersSensex = pd.read_html(wiki+'BSE_SENSEX')[1].Symbol.to_list()
tikersDOW = pd.read_html(wiki+'Dow_Jones_Industrial_Average')[1].Symbol.to_list()


def getdata(tickers):
    data = []
    for ticker in tickers:
        data.append(yf.download(ticker).reset_index())
    return


india, US = getdata(tikersSensex), getdata(tikersDOW)


def createengine(name):
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///'+name)
    return engine


indiaengine, USengine = createengine('India'), createengine('USA')


def TOSQL(frames, symbols, engine):
    for frame,symbol in zip(frames,symbols):
        frame.to_sql(symbol, engine, index=False)
    print('Successfully imported data')


TOSQL(india, tikersSensex, indiaengine)```
````

Comment: It's unclear where that error appears.

Comment: Post the full traceback.

Comment: `getdata()` doesn't return anything; `return` is equivalent to `return None`. What are you expecting to assign to `india` and `US`?

Comment: `TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [14], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 TOSQL(india, tikersSensex, indiaengine)

Input In [13], in TOSQL(frames, symbols, engine)
      1 def TOSQL(frames, symbols, engine):
----> 2     for frame,symbol in zip(frames,symbols):
      3         frame.to_sql(symbol, engine, index=False)
      4     print('Successfully imported data')

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Comment: I think you meant `return data`

Comment: Oh yes thanks i'm sorry for making this mistake !